# Gap-Degree of non-projective dependency tree

Tags: parsing, dependency-parsing, dependency-tree

The following is how my class defines gap-degree:
The gap-degree of a word in a dependency tree is the least k for which the substring consisting of the word and its descendants is entirely comprised of k +1 contiguous substrings.
The gap-degree of a dependency tree is the greatest gap-degree of any word in the tree.

With the following example:
[Non-projective Dependency Trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYAzB.png)

What is the gap-degree of the above non-projective trees? How do you know?

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to calculate this using the above example.

Comment: Did you figure it out?